# Control Volume Level of Custom Notification Sound in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications

this is more so a question asking about how to approach a problem vs me posting code and asking where the error is.

But I am building a paging system in flutter (to work on both android and ios). As a result, I am using custom sounds in my application (so that I can have sounds stronger than the default OS sound). Because this sounds are naturally louder, I want to give the user the option to control the sound level of the notification (from 0 to 100%). I cannot seem to find any resources that speak on this, but I do know it is possible because I have apps on my phone that allow that (amazon pager app for instance).

**Is there a way to allow a user control the volume level of a notification through the app that was built in flutter?** If it's possible, could i get pointed to a tutorial or article or even sample code?

Comment: Are you using `flutter_local_notifications` plugin to fire notifications?

Comment: Yes I am using that @a0x2

Answer (score 1):

There's no dedicated way to do this but here's a hack to achieve this. You can use any package/widget of your choice like [volume_control](https://pub.dev/packages/volume_control) or [volume_controller](https://pub.dev/packages/volume_controller)

Assuming that you use the first option:

1. Get the system volume by using

> VolumeControl.volume

2. Get user desired volume level values(Using a slider etc).
3. Save both values.
4. Now here you need to set the device notifications/system volume to the user defined values before the notification is played by using

> VolumeControl.setVolume(val)

5. After notification has been played, set the system volume back to the original/previous value.

Same way you can use other widgets.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do something similar recently and I used this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/lecle_volume_flutter). It's well documented and there's some sample code for regulating the volume. I used other packages but none work so well as this one.

You can set the volume with something like this:

```
  late AudioManager audioManager;
  dynamic maxVol,
      currentVol; // Value will be int type on Android device and double type on iOS device

  void setVol({int androidVol = 0, double iOSVol = 0.0}) async {
    await Volume.setVol(
      androidVol: androidVol,
      iOSVol: iOSVol,
      showVolumeUI: false,
    );
  }
```

And then just call the method where you need it and pass the values when changed (in a slider for example).

Hope this helps!